# Get Caption of SID from RSOP_Session SecurityGroups

Tags: vbscript, sid

From the WMI namespace `root\rsop\user\<user_SID>` I can fetch an array of `SecurityGroups` using the WQL `Select SecurityGroups from RSOP_Session`. I end up with a list of SIDs similar to the following:

```
S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-604776629-999
S-1-1-0
S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-682003330-9999
S-1-5-32-545
S-1-5-32-544
S-1-5-4
S-1-5-11
S-1-2-0
S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-604776629-888
S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-604776629-77777
S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-604776629-66666
S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-604776629-55555
S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-604776629-44444
```

My question: How do I retrieve the caption (name) of those SIDs? Some of them belongs to the domain, and yet some others belong to I'm not sure who/what/where... (the problem, of course, is the latter)

Answer (score 2):

Process the SAM and SYSTEM hives with YARU (Yet Another Registry Utility) and generate a Password Hash Report from the Report menu, using the "Extracted hives" option for exported hives and the "Live System" option for the system which you are using.

YARU can be found for download at:

https://www.tzworks.net/download_links.php

YARU is located in the middle of the list under Registry and Event Log Analysis.